# IAR Embedded Workbench. Where is __iar_program_start?

Tags: c, embedded, iar, stm8

In the code for a STM8 application there is a line

```
extern void __iar_program_start(void);
```

now I've searched and this function is nowhere to be found.
What is this and where is located??

Comment: It's the program entry point, usually in `cstartup.s`. I suggest that you read the IAR manual**s** (both for ide and the compiler).

Answer (score 3):

Found it in a module called `cstartup_M.o`  inside a library which is part of the IAR tool installation.

In my case, the library is called `rt7M_tl.a`, but it probably depends on your target CPU.

Answer (score 1):

These function may generate for C version of code, cause this type of instruction you can find in assembly.

```
__iar_program_start:
        LDW     X, #CSTACK$$Limit-1     ; Set stackpointer
        LDW     SP, X
```